# Array of images to be displayed based on %

Tags: jquery, arrays, image

I have a table of with %'s, and I need to run through an array of images and display the correct image based on the %.  So, in td.tri-img if the is 20%, i need to pull the triangle20.png using jquery by the way.

EDIT: So i have this now, with this JS, but can't i do this more efficiently, looping through the td's and pulling in the spans???:

```
function triangleImages() {
var _td = $('td#tri-first');
    var _percentage = $('td#tri-first span').html();
    //get the img element
    var _img = $('img#column1');
    //generate new source for img
    var _img_src = 'img/triangle' + _percentage + '.png';
    //set the src
    _img.attr('src', _img_src);
    }
    triangleImages();
```

here is the table:

```
            <tr class="tri-col">
            <td class="num-label">20</td>
            <td class="tri-img" id="tri-first"><img class="one" id="column1" src="" alt="" ><span>20</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="two" src="" alt="" ><span>30</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="three" src="" alt="" ><span>40</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="four" src="" alt="" ><span>35</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="five" src="" alt="" ><span>23</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="six" src="" alt="" ><span>22</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="seven" src="" alt="" ><span>50</span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="eight" src="img/triangle.png" alt="" ><span></span><span>&#37;</span></td>
            <td class="tri-img"><img class="nine" src="img/triangle.png" alt="" ><span></span><span>&#37;</span></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
var _tds = jQuery('td.tri-img');
```

you can use jQuery.each over _tds and then use jQuery('unique-td').children('span').html() to get the width

```
//get the td element
var _td = jQuery('#td_id');
var _width = _td.attr('width');
//remove % from width
var _width = _width.substr(0, _width.length - 1);
//get the img element
var _img = jQuery('#img_id');
//generate new source for img
var _img_src = 'img/triangle' + _width + '.png';
//set the src
_img.attr('src', _img_src);
```

Comment: i removed the %, and its not based on the width, it is based on the number in <span>, so the first is 20.  Can I do a loop through td.tri-img grabbing the <span> value, and then assigning it that way?

Comment: var _td = $("td.tri-img span");
$.each(_td, function(i){
console.log( $(i));
});    I am trying this but I am not getting the values, if I attach .html(); to the variable it only gives me the first value?